# FFmpeg command usage

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to encode raw yuv video to get streams at various bitrates by libx264 as videocodec in ffmpeg command. Here it is :

`ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i D:\TestSeqncs\crowd_run_1080p25.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000K C:\Users\sree\Desktop\FFmpeg_Experiment\crowd1080p5.264 -s 1280x720 -b:v 4000K C:\Users\sree\Desktop\FFmpeg_Experiment\crowd720p4.264 -s 704x576 -b:v 2000K C:\Users\sree\Desktop\FFmpeg_Experiment\crowd704p2.264`.

I got my output also.

Then I want to mux theses streams to get single transport stream, Here it is :

`" ffmpeg.exe -i crowd1080p5.264 -i crowd720p4.264 -i crowd704p2.264 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 muxout.ts "`.

But My task is to do both operations in same command ( without using && and ffmpeg again in same command), Please help me if anyone have idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i D:\TestSeqncs\crowd_run_1080p25.yuv -lavfi "[0:v]split=2[in2][in3];[in2]scale=1280x720[out2];[in3]scale=704x576[out3]" -map 0:v -map "[out2]" -map "[out3]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v:0 5000K -b:v:1 4000K -b:v:2 2000K muxout.ts
```

Comment: Thanks Mulvya. I got single TS. Its really helpful in my work .